# How to filter nodes based on certain condition of the child node text

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an XML file as shown below.

```
<COLLECTION>
    <ChangedParts>
       <Part>
          <number>123456</number>
          <DefaultUnit>each</DefaultUnit>
          <FgOrComponent>FG</FgOrComponent>
          <MasterPackUom/>
          <CartonUom/>
       </Part>
       <Part>
          <number>456789</number>
          <DefaultUnit>each</DefaultUnit>         
          <FgOrComponent>COMPONENT</FgOrComponent>
          <MasterPackUom/>
          <CartonUom/>
       </Part>
    </ChangedParts>
</COLLECTION>
```

I am trying to use XSLT to transform the file.  The file contains Part elements with FgOrComponent and some other elements as its child nodes.  FgOrComponent has either FG or COMPONENT has it value.  I need to select only the Part element with FG as its value for the FgOrComponent element and modify some other elements like  etc in the selected part.  The expected output is as shown below.

```
<COLLECTION>
    <ChangedParts>
       <Part>
          <name>123456</name>
          <DefaultUnit>ea</DefaultUnit>
          <FgOrComponent>FG</FgOrComponent>
          <MasterPackUom>mp</MasterPackUom>
          <CartonUom>ca</CartonUom>
       </Part>
       <Part>
          <number>456789</number>
          <DefaultUnit>each</DefaultUnit>         
          <FgOrComponent>COMPONENT</FgOrComponent>
          <MasterPackUom/>
          <CartonUom/>
       </Part>
    </ChangedParts>
</COLLECTION>
```

I am using the following XSLT file to do the transformation without any success.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>           
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="/*/*/Part[(FgOrComponent = 'FG')]/*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="MasterPackUom/text() = ''">
                <MasterPackUom>mp</MasterPackUom>           
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>          
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The test clause "MasterPackUom/text() = '' is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

If the element is empty then it doesn't have any `text()` node children, just check `MasterPackUom = ''`.

But as you have the identity transformation set up as a base transformation, please simply write templates for the relevant changes e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="Part[FgOrComponent = 'FG']/MasterPackUom[. = '']">
  <xsl:copy>mp</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

instead of doing that odd xsl:choose.